# JSreport and NodeJS, How to generate report using jsreport on nodejs without server?

Tags: node.js, report, electron, desktop-application, jsreport

I am working on a project, where my application need to generate a report. So I searched for the library that generate report for me and I got "JSreport". Then I started to dig that to get dirt with that.

Now, my requirement is that the application which I'm gonna develop has to be stand alone, but as per my understanding with JSreport, it needs a server to generate a report(i.e. my application has to communicate with the server of JSreport to generate the report), but my application has to work offline. So I am worried about it.

Is there a way to make it work offline without any server? If so, please help me to come-out of this. Or please suggest me a good report generating library that will satisfy my requirements.

Note: My application gonna be with nodejs and electronjs, so please suggest the libraries related to those languages.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try set up a local JSReport server from you application.
You should be able to communicate with it sending requests to `localhost:${port}`. It doesn't require to have internet connection.

See https://jsreport.net/on-prem

Comment: Tried that but its not helping, while trying to start it, it keep on throwing an error as "Start command not found, install jsreport-cli or package". Any suggestions for that is welcomed...

Comment: How do you start it?

Comment: The exact way on the webpage.

Comment: i guess that the "jsreport start" does not work for you because your project structure is a bit different than normal jsreport project generated by "jsreport init", info about the requirements of the cli, here https://jsreport.net/learn/cli#node-js-project-integration.

you mentioned that your app is a desktop app using electron, in that case the best for you is to start jsreport from nodejs itself rather than using the "jsreport start" command, you need to use the `.init` method, more info about using jsreport from nodejs here https://jsreport.net/learn/adapting-jsreport

Comment: @BJRMatos, Thanks for your valuable guide, now I can able to use it offline, but the concern is I can't able to start the server of jsreport automatically along with the app initialization, I'm doing it manually everytime. I'm glad if you help me to fix this.